# Exactly what was Surveyor 3 doing with a spring-loaded boxing glove-like device?

Tags: identify-this-object, lander, mechanisms, surveyor-program, surveyor-3

The thorough moon.NASA.gov/exploration page [Moon Missions](https://moon.nasa.gov/exploration/moon-missions/) shows the image below.

I learned almost all of what I know about Physics and Engineering from the [Wile E. Coyote and the Road Runner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wile_E._Coyote_and_the_Road_Runner) cartoons, from the [Looney Tunes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looney_Tunes) and [Merrie Melodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merrie_Melodies) series of cartoons.

I instantly recognized the apparatus on the Surveyor 3 lander extending in front of Apollo 12 commander Charles Conrad Jr. as a spring loaded boxing glove, adapted more recently (either from the Surveyor 3 or the Coyote's implementation) by a [Wallace and Gromit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace_and_Gromit) mission shown below.

**Question:** But I'd like to know exactly what was Surveyor 3 doing with a spring-loaded boxing glove-like device?

---

[image]

Source: https://moon.nasa.gov/exploration/moon-missions/

> Apollo 12 commander Charles Conrad Jr. examines the robotic Surveyor 3 spacecraft during his second extravehicular activity (EVA) on the Moon on 20 November 1969.

Full size [available here](https://moon.nasa.gov/resources/31/man-and-machine/) where the caption says

> Apollo 12 astronaut Alan L. Bean, lunar module pilot, examines the robotic Surveyor 3 spacecraft during his second extravehicular activity (EVA) on the Moon on 20 November 1969. Surveyor spacecraft pioneered the technology that enabled Apollo astronauts to reach the Moon.
>
> The Lunar Module (LM) Intrepid is in the background (right). This picture was taken by commander Charles Conrad Jr.
>
> Intrepid landed on the Moon's Ocean of Storms on 19 November 1969 only about 600 feet (180 meters) from the Surveyor 3 spacecraft.
>
> The television camera and several other components were taken from Surveyor 3 and brought back to Earth for scientific analysis.

Because of the conflict in names, I've just asked [Which Apollo 12 astronaut is shown examining the Surveyor 3 lander in this photograph?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38475/12102)

Comment: Did you mean [one fo these](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-boxing-glove-on-scissor-spring-124123416.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the soil sampling arm and scoop.

> This Surveyor mission was the first one that carried a surface-soil
>   sampling-scoop, which can be seen on its extendable arm in the
>   pictures. This mechanism was mounted on an electric-motor-driven arm
>   and was used to dig four trenches in the lunar soil. These trenches
>   were up to seven inches (18 centimeters) deep. Samples of soil from
>   the trenches were placed in front of the Surveyor's television cameras
>   to be photographed and the pictures radioed back to the Earth.

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surveyor_3))

The Apollo 12 crew brought the scoop back!  It is currently in the Kansas Cosmosphere.

Good article on it [here](https://www.caltech.edu/about/news/one-metal-scoop-slightly-used-37551).

[image]
[image]

Images from the Heroic Relics scoop [page](http://heroicrelics.org/cosmosphere/surveyor-3-scoop/index.html).

(apparently *not* made by Acme)