# Which Apollo 12 astronaut is shown examining the Surveyor 3 lander in this photograph?

Tags: astronauts, identify-this-object, apollo-12, surveyor-program, surveyor-3

I used this image in [Exactly what was Surveyor 3 doing with a spring-loaded boxing glove-like device?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38474/12102) but in the captions for the image on two NASA sites I noticed a disagreement in the identify of the astronaut shown examining the Surveyor 3 lander.

[image]

Source: https://moon.nasa.gov/exploration/moon-missions/

> **Apollo 12 commander Charles Conrad Jr. examines the robotic Surveyor 3 spacecraft** during his second extravehicular activity (EVA) on the Moon on 20 November 1969.

Full size [available here](https://moon.nasa.gov/resources/31/man-and-machine/) where the caption says

> **Apollo 12 astronaut Alan L. Bean, lunar module pilot, examines the robotic Surveyor 3 spacecraft** during his second extravehicular activity (EVA) on the Moon on 20 November 1969. Surveyor spacecraft pioneered the technology that enabled Apollo astronauts to reach the Moon.
>
> The Lunar Module (LM) Intrepid is in the background (right). **This picture was taken by commander Charles Conrad Jr.**
>
> Intrepid landed on the Moon's Ocean of Storms on 19 November 1969 only about 600 feet (180 meters) from the Surveyor 3 spacecraft.
>
> The television camera and several other components were taken from Surveyor 3 and brought back to Earth for scientific analysis.

**Question:** Which astronaut is shown examining the Surveyor 3 lander in this photograph?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be precise, the astronaut is posing for a "tourist picture", rather than examining Surveyor.

This is photo AS12-48-7136 (very similar to -7135, but distinguishable by the position of the Réseau marks), with some contrast changes. According to the [Apollo 12 image library](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a12/images12.html#Mag48), there was some back and forth of cameras and magazines because of a mechanical problem, but this particular shot was of Al Bean, taken by Pete Conrad.

A picture (AS12-48-7133) taken slightly earlier is claimed to be of Conrad, distinguishable at that point in the EVA because he had a set of tongs attached at his waist. Bean doesn't have the tongs. There are detailed notes in the [Apollo 12 Lunar Surface Journal](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a12/a12.surveyor.html#1341614) at 134:16:14 discussing who's taking pictures of who, and how to be sure. 7135 & 7136 are taken at about 134:17:42.

[image]

Comment: further discussion of "space tourist" photos in [How did Apollo-12 manage to land next to Surveyor-3? First “Space-Tourists”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20353/12102)

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out! I'm having trouble spotting the aforementioned tongs, is it possible to help point out where they are somehow?

Comment: I think they're the bit that looks like a small broom, below, parallel to, and brighter than the last downward strut of Surveyor's scoop-arm assembly that's the subject of your other question.

Comment: Oh, there it is! [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34617/12102) mentions the use of a stripe to identify one astronaut from another "after Apollo 11", but I don't know if it's going to be visible here, the suits are somewhat overexposed.

Comment: No commander stripes on 12 either, I'm afraid. There's a good discussion in the [A12LSJ](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a12/a12.surveyor.html#1341614) just before these pics were taken about how to tell them apart.

Comment: The [NASA reference link](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/alsj-CDRStripes.html) in the answer about the stripes says they were added for A13 (which obviously didn't have ambiguous lunar surface photography) and subsequent.